# How to Create Database Using Python Keyword Search?

Tags: python

**STATEMENT OF THE PROBLEM**

Suppose I have three text files named myfile1.txt, myfile2.txt and myfile3.txt saved in a folder named c:\myfiles. I also have a list of 3 keywords: kw1, kw2 and kw3 listed in a comma delimited text file called kwfile.txt which is also saved in the c:\myfiles folder. (Uppercase, lowercase etc. do not matter; only the actual words matter; the source files may have words in upper or lower cases.)

How do I write a Python code/script that will read all the myfile*.txt files in the c:\myfiles, search for the keywords mentioned in kwfile.txt, # of distinct words, and # of total words and export the results creating a simple comma delimited text file (that can be easily exported to excel) with the following columns?

1. File name
2. Total # of words
3. # of distinct words
4. # of times kw1 appears in the file
5. # of times kw2 appears in the file
6. # of times kw3 appears in the file

**VERSION ISSUES**

I understand that there are some significant differences between 2.7 and 3.4 versions. Which one is better for this example?

Comment: I recommend you program in Python 3.  Python 2 is to be retired.  Learning it (and working around it's limitations) makes you gain little of value for the future.

Comment: it looks like, make my homework, and I will pay you 25+ reputation.

Comment: This was not a homework question. I can now see that it might sounded like one. I am merely curious to know how writers reflect on the same events when they write/report. It came from my deep interest in reading newspapers from around the world.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really define what the difference is between the total number of words and the number of distinct words. However, this is a fairly trivial exercise where I would recommend using Python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) and [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) modules. You can use the glob module to grab a list of the files to search in and the csv module to create the comma separated result.

I created a super simple example program that you might find useful:

```
import csv
from glob import glob

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def find_words(myfile, fh):

    number_of_words = 0
    kw1 = 0
    kw2 = 0
    kw3 = 0
    for line in fh:
        words = line.split()
        number_of_words += len(words)
        for word in words:
            w = word.lower()
            if "kw1" == w:
                kw1 += 1
            elif "kw2" == w:
                kw2 += 1
            elif "kw3" == w:
                kw3 += 1

    with open("words.csv", "ab") as csv_fh:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_fh)
        data = [myfile, number_of_words, number_of_words, kw1, kw2, kw3]
        writer.writerow(data)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main(path):

    myfiles = glob(path + "/myfile*.txt")
    for myfile in myfiles:
        with open(myfile) as fh:
            find_words(myfile, fh)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(r"c:\myfiles")
```

This example does have at least one serious limitation. For example, if the keywords have punctuation next to them, then the counters for those keywords will be incorrect as they will fail the equality test.

This code is also based on the Python 2.x version of the csv module. The only thing you would need to change in this code to make it Python 3 compatible is to change the `open("words.csv", "ab")` line to `open("words.csv", "a")` and it should just work.

Comment: I am sincerely grateful for your detailed response. You are a great teacher. I learned a great deal from your answer. THANK YOU!

Comment: import re
import collections
kwords = ['kw1', 'kw2', 'kw3']
words = re.findall('\w+', open('myfile1.txt').read().lower())
cnt = collections.Counter()
for word in words:
    if word in kwords:
        cnt[word] += 1
print 'MYFILE1'
print cnt 
# My_results: 415,31,33; 
# Your_result 263,23,21; 
# what am I doing wrong? Please guide

Comment: If a lot of the words are next to punctuation, my solution won't pick it up as I am only matching on those 3 letters. Using a regular expression correctly would probably be better as they can ignore punctuation. You could print out what strings you're matching against to see what you're counting.

Answer (score 0):

Something dirty could be:

```
import sys
import re

# Check for usage
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage: %s <file>" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(-1)

# Get keywords
kwfile = open('kwfile.txt', 'r')
kws = [x.strip() for x in kwfile.readlines()]
kwfile.close()

# Get Data
data = {}
totalwords = 0
diffwords = 0
infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for word in re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', infile.read()):
    if word in data:
        data[word] += 1
        diffwords += 1
    else:
        data[word] = 1
    totalwords += 1
infile.close()

# Format output
out = ("File name: %s\n" % sys.argv[1] +
       "Total %d of words\n" % totalwords +
       "%d distinct words\n" % diffwords
       )
for k in kws:
    try:
        kwtimes = data[k]
    except KeyError:
        kwtimes = 0
    out += "%d times keyword %s appears in the file\n" % (kwtimes, k)

# Write output
outfile = open(sys.argv[1][:-3] + 'out', 'w')
outfile.write(out)
outfile.close()

# Show output
print out
```

Of course you can always add it modularity, error checking, and so for.

Also, as suggested in some comments, you should ask specific/particular questions not ask for homework.

Comment: Sincerely grateful for your answer. This was not a homework question. I can now see that it might sounded like one. I am merely curious to know how writers reflect on the same events when they write/report. It came from my deep interest in reading newspapers from around the world. I am very lucky to live in a world with so many wonderful, gracious, helpful people like yourself. THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem. On my part I thank that this beautiful site exists. x)